# undefined reference while using shared library

Tags: shared-libraries, undefined-reference

**I want to use one program as a shared library for an other program.**

I started as follows:
I have a application which I have compiled using:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -I/usr/include/libxml2  -Xlinker -zmuldefs -fPIC -c a.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -I/usr/include/libxml2  -Xlinker -zmuldefs -fPIC -c b.cpp
/usr/bin/g++ -I/usr/include/libxml2  -Xlinker -zmuldefs -fPIC -c c.cpp
```

Then I have created a shared object library from the objects I get from this file using this command:

```
g++ -fPIC -Xlinker -zmuldefs -shared -o libabc.so a.o b.o c.o
```

After this I get the libabc.so file which I copy to the

```
sudo cp libabc.so /usr/local/lib/libabc.so
```

Now when I compile my orignal application which will use this newly created library **libabc.so** using this command:

```
/usr/local/lib/libabd.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewContext'
```

I get errors for all the functions I used from the included library libxml2 in the first application and the function which has this undefined reference is actually the library I include in the first program I mean I have tested it.
So kindly anyone guide me where I need corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to pass the path also using `-I/path/to/library`, or alternatively export it to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: i tried this but it still says that the 
 `/usr/include/lib/libabc.so :undefined reference to "xmlXPathNewContext"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the command line that you used to link your application against your library, but I suppose that adding `-lxml2` to the flags passed to the linker should solve the problem.

Comment: We cannot help more without having more details: is `libxml2` installed system wide (i.e., is a there a `/usr/lib/libxml2*so` file)? What is the commandline used to build your application? If you try to use some `libxml2` functions directly from your application, can the linker solve those references?

Comment: libxml2 is a library  
 `$ ls -h /usr/lib/libxml2.*` 
returns
 `/usr/lib/libxml2.a   /usr/lib/libxml2.so    /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
/usr/lib/libxml2.la  /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2`

i have used these commands to build my application
 `/usr/bin/g++ -I/usr/include/libxml2  -Xlinker -zmuldefs -fPIC -c  neoclassic.cc`

Comment: when i used `-llibxml2` it gives error
 `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibxml2`

Comment: when i run my main application
`g++ -lneoclassic -lrt -o common/ptypes2tcl common/ptypes2tcl.o`
`/usr/local/lib/libneoclassic.so: undefined reference to 'xmlXPathNewContext'`
so i thought to look through my libneoclassic.so
`nm -D /usr/local/lib/lneoclassic.so | grep xmlXPathNewContext`
and it returned me
`U xmlXPathNewContext`

Comment: When you link your application you need to add `-lxml2` to the command line; **beware** it's `-lxml2`, not `-llibxml2`. So, use `g++ -lneoclassic -lrt -lxml2 -o common/ptypes2tcl common/ptypes2tcl.o`

Comment: i tried but was not working so i tried `g++ -o common/ptypes2tcl common/ptypes2tcl.o -lneoclassic -lrt -lxml2` and it worked like a charm.
i think i need to learn about Makefiles. 
but thank @marco-leogrande